# Проблема c указанием автора при создании объекта | DRF

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

Моя проблема заключается в том, что одно представление обеспечивает пользователя функционалом для создания объявления, но мой сериализатор не допускает возможности выбрать автора. (Было бы глупо, если бы создающий объявление пользователь мог выбрать не себя, а скажем админа)

Но вот проблема, соответственно и заполнить исключенное поле из сериализатора request.user'ом я не могу.

Мой код:

**Модель**

```
class Ad(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True
    )
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    )
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=80,
    )
    text = models.TextField(
        max_length=256,
    )
    cost = models.PositiveIntegerField(

    )
    currency = models.ForeignKey(
        Currency,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    )
    city = models.ForeignKey(
        City,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    )
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True
    )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-pub_date']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**Сериализатор**

```
class AdSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Ad
        exclude = ['author']
```

**Представление**

```
class CreateMixin(views.APIView):
    """Allows heirs to use the same method of creating objects."""
    serializer_class = permission_classes = None

    def post(self, request):
        """Creates an object and, if everything is successful,
         returns its serialized form to the user."""
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid() and serializer.save():
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

class CreateAd(CreateMixin):
    """Provides functionality for creating an ad."""
    serializer_class = serializers.AdSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]
```

Представление для создания объявления я вместе с другими унаследовал от своего миксина. Понятное дело, что при появлении возможности присвоить полю объекта автора я перестану наследовать, т.к миксин предоставляет ограниченный рамками абстракции функционал, следовательно на него внимания не обращайте)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение нашел в дополнительном сериализаторе, который отвечает за создание и модификацию объявлений.

Один сериализатор для того, чтобы во вьюсете выводить список объявлений со всеми полями, а другой для того, чтобы минуя поле author во избежание лишних кликов по нему, создавать объявление.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, вы сами себя в угол загнали. Верните author в сериализатор, и сделайте [проверенным способом](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35520084/6053444).

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: 1. Не думаю, что ссылка на англоязычный SO является по отношению к RU.SO внешним ресурсом.
2. По ссылке представлено несколько вариантов решения проблемы, в зависимости от дополнительных обстоятельств.

Comment: я попробовал таким способом. Если вернуть в сериализатор поле author, то любой аутентифицированный пользователь сможет выбирать автора объявления. Мне это не нужно. Я пришел к выводу, что стоит написать два сериализатора под одну модель. Один это обычный AdSerializer, а другой это ModifierAdSerializer, который включает в себя инструкции по созданию и обновлению объекта. Что думаете по этому поводу?

Comment: И да, hidden field мне тоже не поможет. В одном представлении я демонстрирую объявления, а в другом создаю, соответственно кроме создания нового сериализатора под одну и ту же модель выхода я не нахожу.

Comment: @CrazyTheory каким же образом пользователь сможет выбирать автора объявления, если автор жёстко задаётся из request.user?

Comment: Поле в форме метода POST то остается) Даже если после создания введенное значение пользователем переопределится благодаря моим кодовым инструкциям, Вы считаете эстетичным то, что такой филд отображается при создании?

Comment: Я просто не использую прилагающийся к DRF фронтенд, и с такой проблемой не сталкивался :) Возможно, как-то можно убрать это поле, используя стили: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/html-and-forms/#field-styles
если же нет, тогда, видимо, да, остаётся только другой сериалайзер.

Comment: да, я тоже не использую, это стандартная форма, которую предоставляет DRF, когда определяешь POST запрос в классе представления. В любом случае спасибо за то, что попробовали мне помочь) Воспользуюсь дополнительным сериализатором.